# Canvas text rotate and move

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to add text to the canvas and move the whole canvas then. 
When I'm just adding the text everything works fine. 
But when I try to move the canvas the text is moving strange.

[image: My canvas]

[image: Canvas with text]

[image: Canvas after move attempt]

As you can see, when I'm moving the canvas the text is moving not like it supposed to be.

How can I fix it?

```
function renderTextCanvas() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, viewportOffsetX, viewportOffsetY, img.width, img.height);

textComponents.forEach(function (textObj) {
    ctx.save();
    var offsetX = textObj.x;
    var offsetY = textObj.y;

    ctx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctx.rotate(textObj.rotation);
    ctx.translate(-offsetX, -offsetY);
    ctx.font = textObj.fontSize + 'px ' + textObj.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = textObj.color;


    if (textObj.saved) {
        ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x + viewportOffsetX, textObj.y + viewportOffsetY);
    }
    else {
        ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x, textObj.y);
        textObj.saved = true;
        textObj.x -= viewportOffsetX;
        textObj.y -= viewportOffsetY;
    }
    ctx.restore();
});
```

Viewport offsets are being changed on drag:

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        var pageX = e.pageX;
        var pageY = e.pageY;

        if (e.touches) {
            var touches = e.touches[0];
            pageX = touches.pageX;
            pageY = touches.pageY;
        }

        var deltaX = pageX - originX;
        var deltaY = pageY - originY;

        if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetX) < Math.abs(img.width / 2)) {
            viewportOffsetX += deltaX;
        }
        else {
            if (viewportOffsetX < 0) {
                viewportOffsetX += 1;
            }
            else {
                viewportOffsetX -= 1;
            }
        }
        if (Math.abs(viewportOffsetY) < Math.abs(img.height / 2)) {
            viewportOffsetY += deltaY;
        }
        else {
            if (viewportOffsetY < 0) {
                viewportOffsetY += 1;
            }
            else {
                viewportOffsetY -= 1;
            }
        }
        originX = pageX;
        originY = pageY;
        renderTextCanvas();
    }
}
```